# handling json data in php from jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-post

I created a json with this structure

```
var data = 
{ 
    "people": [ 
      { "name" : "John", "id" : 1 },
      { "name" : "Marc", "id" : 2 }
     ] 
}
```

Now here's how i send the data to the php

```
var ordenDeCompra = JSON.stringify(data);
$.post("../Backend/ordenesDeCompra.php",
    {
        ventas: data, 
        idcliente : $('#sltCliente').val(),
        subtotal: subtotalfactura
    },
respuesta);
```

Now when i tried to handle the data in the php it doesn't have any values, i know that the values are sending well, because i see the data sending with `charles debugging proxy`.

This is how i tried the get the value in the php

```
$array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['ventas']), true);
```

Am i sending the values corrected??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
ventas: data,
```

to

```
ventas: ordenDeCompra,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var ordenDeCompra = JSON.stringify(data);
$.post("../Backend/ordenesDeCompra.php",
    {
        ventas: ordenDeCompra, 
        idcliente : $('#sltCliente').val(),
        subtotal: subtotalfactura
    },
respuesta);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ordenDeCompra = JSON.stringify(data);
$.post("../Backend/ordenesDeCompra.php",
    {
        ventas: ordenDeCompra, // shouldn't it be ordenDeCompra than data
        idcliente : $('#sltCliente').val(),
        subtotal: subtotalfactura
    },
respuesta);
```